# GeoLocate control stopped working in Chrome on iOs

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Does anyone know if something changed in Chrome on iPhones that prevents the GeoLocate control from working? My own website now just shows a spinning icon when I tap the control (I am allowing location tracking) and even the MapBox example page https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/locate-user/ gives me the same result - just a spinning icon. It works in Safari for me. I've restarted Chrome and also my phone and I've tried on another iPhone with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Chrome permissions from 'allow access to location while using app' to 'allow once' solved this for me.